# Proxy tool for CoAP integrated with DTLS

Tags: ssl, cryptography, dtls, coap

How to view the request/response for **CoAP** protocol integrated with **DTLS**.

**Copper** *(firefox plugin)*
tool works fine with CoAP protocol without DTLS. for e.g.

> coap://localhost:5683

request/response can be easily viewed and modified. 
When DTLS is integrated with CoAP for e.g.

> coaps://localhost:5683

request/response is not visible using copper tool.
  Need information on any other proxy tool/plugin through which request/response can be viewed and the request can be modified.

Comment: There's [CoAP for Wireshark](https://github.com/jessezha/CoAP-For-Wireshark), would that be any help? Oh, sheesh, June 11, sorry about that, I was just (re-)visiting the DTLS questions. Any success by now?